# Is using synchronization in service layer a bad idea?

Tags: web-services, concurrency

I need to implement a mailbox monitor system as a web service. I have follow classes:

`MailboxMonitor`: Contains information such as username, password, pulling interval etc.

`MailboxMonitorRepository`: Retrieve and store `MailboxMonitor` from database.

`ExternalService`: Retrive and process emails based on the given `MailboxMonitor`instance.

Here is some code snippet:

```
MailboxMonitorController{
    public void update(MailboxMonitor monitor){
        mailboxService.update(monitor);
    }
}

MailboxMonitorService{
    public void update(MailboxMonitor monitor){
        synchronized(this){
            mailboxMonitorRepository.update(monitor);
            externalService.update(monitor);
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I use synchonization here is try to handle race condition.
Suppose `threadA` update a monitor pulling interval to 5 minutes and at same time `threadB` try to update the **same** monitor's interval to 1 minute. Here is a poosible execution path without synchronization:

threadA update database --> threadB update database --> threadB update external service --> threadA update external service

What it ends with is database claims the pulling interval is 1 minute, however, the external service pulls and processes emails every 5 minutes.

Adding synchronization here will hurt performance. Threads trying to update different monitors will block each other. I feel I am doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: `Adding synchronization here will hurt performance` -- You don't know that unless you measure it.  In any case, your implementation seems flawed; I can't think of any good reason why you would need to pass around a monitor object, and you don't even appear to be synchronizing on the monitor object you're passing around anyway.

Comment: In any case, won't this problem fix itself in 5 minutes anyway?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am not sure why i need to syn on the monitor object. The `MailboxMonitorRepository` will read the attribute from the monitor and update database . ExternalService is also just reading attribute of monitor and make a copy of some attribute (like username, password, interval ) they don't modify the monitor. And i am also confused why it will fix itself?

Comment: Then I guest "monitor" means something different to me than it does to you.  It will fix itself, because in 5 minutes the external service will check the pulling interval again and go "Oh, it's one minute now."

Comment: @RobertHarvey I understand. Instead of telling the `ExternalService` that the pulling interval is set to XXX minutes, we just tell it something is updated. Go ask database to get the up to date value.

Comment: Yes.  Or the external service simply checks after every pull to see if the interval has changed.